# How does Syndrome-Trellis Code (STC) work?

Tags: steganography

Syndrome-trellis code was introduced to minimize embedding distortion in steganography. See this paper: **[Minimizing Embedding Impact in Steganography using Trellis-Coded Quantization](http://dde.binghamton.edu/filler/pdf/Fill10spie-syndrome-trellis-codes.pdf)**.

#### Background information

The following paragraph can be found [on this website](http://dde.binghamton.edu/download/syndrome/):

> Syndrome-trellis codes are essentially binary linear convolutional
> codes represented by parity-check matrix. This representation allows
> to use them for information embedding problems, where no channel code
> is required.

The diagram below shows an example of STC taken from the paper. It was said that the goal is to find a vector $y$ such that $Hy=m$ where $H$ is the shared parity-check matrix between the sender and receiver, and $m$ is the secret message to be communicated. I understood the vector $y$ as the resulting stego-image that will be communicated to the receiver, whom will then be able to extract $m$ using the shared $H$. 

 

Each $y$ satisfying $Hy=m$ is represented as a path through the trellis, where the path starts in the leftmost all-zero state and extends to the right.  The path shows the step-by-step calculation of the (partial) syndrome using more and more bits of $y$. For example, the first two edges in Figure 2, that connect the state 00 from column $p0$ with states 11 and 00 in the next column, correspond to adding $(y1 = 1)$ or not adding $(y1 = 0)$ the first column of $H$ to the syndrome, respectively. In general, we call the state in the trellis *reachable*, if there is a path connecting this state with the leftmost all-zero state.

I do not understand this part of [the paper named at the top](http://dde.binghamton.edu/filler/pdf/Fill10spie-syndrome-trellis-codes.pdf) (p. 5):

> From each reachable state, two edges extend to the right; they correspond to adding or not adding the next column of matrix **H** to the current partial syndrome and are labeled 1 and 0, respectively. The edge labels along the path in the trellis thus correspond to individual bits of the stego object **y**.

#### Question

How does the reachable state extend to the right? It was said that there are only 2 extensions per reachable state and each correspond to adding/not adding the next column of matrix **H** and are labelled 1 and 0 respectively. For the column $p0$, it was extended to state 00 and 11. The state 11 is to add the first column "11" of the matrix **H**?  However, in the next column to the right of $p0$ at state 00, the node extends to state 00 and state 10. Why does it extend to 10 and not 01 since 01 is the next column of the matrix **H**?


**Figure 2**, from p. 7 of "Minimizing Embedding Impact in Steganography using Trellis-Coded Quantization":

[image: STC Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add or not add the following column using an XOR operation. Let me explain the first states.

**From $p_0$ to $1$:**

We are in the $00$ state, if we do nothing, we continue in the $00$ state.
But if we add $11$ (first H column) we go to state $11 = 00 \oplus 11$.

**From $1$ to $2$:**

If we are in the $00$ state and we do nothing, we continue in the 00 state, but if we add $10$ (second H column) we go to state $10 = 10 \oplus 00$.
If we are in the $11$ state and we do nothing, we continue in the $11$ state, but if we add $10$ (second H column) we go to state $01 = 10 \oplus 11$.

**From $p_1$ to $3$:**

If we are in the $00$ state and we do nothing, we continue in the $00$ state, but if we add $11$ (third H column) we go to state $11 = 00 \oplus 11$.
If we are in the $01$ state and we do nothing, we continue in the $01$ state, but if we add $11$ (third H column) we go to state $10 = 01 \oplus 11$).

And the same with the following states.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!