# How to build a syndrome trellis from the parity check matrix

Tags: steganography

**Background**

In the paper ["Minimizing Embedding Impact in Steganography using
Trellis-Coded Quantization"](http://dde.binghamton.edu/filler/pdf/Fill10spie-syndrome-trellis-codes.pdf) and in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/93401/how-does-syndrome-trellis-code-stc-work) on this forum, a so called Syndrome Trellis is built from a parity check matrix. The figure below shows the example from the paper, where the trellis on the right is built from matrix $\hat{\mathbb{H}}$.

[image: Example of Syndrome Trellis from paper1]

**Question**

Why does the edge from trellis column $1$ to $2$ go from state $00$ to $10$?
I would have expected it to go from state $00$ to $01$, as the second column of $\hat{\mathbb{H}}$ is $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $00 \oplus 01 = 01$.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you have come up with an answer, you can move it to an answer below. It's ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I think, I figured it out:
The states seem to store the current value of the syndrome, so of $\mathbf{m}=\mathbb{H}y$, where the least significant bit of the state corresponds to that entry of $\mathbf{m}$ with the *smallest index* that is currently affected by the calculation.

In the example:

#### From trellis column $p_0$ to $1$:

The structure of $\mathbb{H}$ is such that only $\mathbb{m}_1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2$ can change, if $y_1$ is assigned a value.

- State $00$ means: currently, both $\mathbb{m}_1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2$ are $0$. If $y_1=0$ nothing changes. If $y_1 =1$, then the partial syndrome reads $\mathbb{m}_1=1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2=1$. Thus, we go to state $11$.

#### From trellis column $1$ to $2$:

Still, only $\mathbb{m}_1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2$ are affected by the assignment of a value to $y_2$.

- State $00$ means: currently, both $\mathbb{m}_1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2$ are $0$. If $y_2=0$ nothing changes. If $y_2 =1$, then the partial syndrome reads $\mathbb{m}_1=0$ and $\mathbb{m}_2=1$. Thus, we go to state $10$.
  This corresponds to evaluating $00 \oplus 10 = 10$, where the second column $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$ of $\hat{\mathbb{H}}$ is interpreted as $10$ to match the states.
- State $11$ means: currently, both $\mathbb{m}_1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2$ are $1$. If $y_2=0$ nothing changes. If $y_2=1$, the the partial syndrome reads $\mathbb{m}_1 = 1$ and $\mathbb{m}_2 = 0$, which corresponds to state $01$.

#### From trellis column $2$ to $p_1$:

$\mathbb{m}_1$ cannot be affected anymore, so the least significant bit of the state now stores the current value of $\mathbb{m}_2$ and the second least significant bit the one of $\mathbb{m}_3$.

Though it is still unclear to me why this is done in this manner, I am happy to have figured that the states encode $\mathbb{m}$ with the least significant bit corresponding to the current entry of $\mathbb{m}$.